# Formulário com anexo no CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, anexo

Boa tarde.

Precisei implementar uma seção para envio de currículos pelo site, porém o anexo não está funcionando, sequer o script consegue ler $_FILES mesmo tendo no formulário o atributo * enctype="multipart/form-data"*, ele vai sempre vazio. O que pode ser?

Comment: Posta o código do form

Comment: Ok, segue abaixo.

Answer (score 0):

Formulário (view):

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(lang())?>/trabalhe-conosco/enviar" method="post" class="formulario-contato fonte-padrao-titulos" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col col-30 fl">
        <label class="opacity">Hidden</label>
        <div class="clearfix file-box">
            <div class="fake-input"><?php echo set_value('userfile')?></div>
            <label class="file-button-send <?php echo (form_error('userfile')) ? 'error' : '' ?>" for="userfile">
                ANEXAR CURRÍCULO
                <input class="hide<?php echo (form_error('userfile')) ? ' error' : '' ?>" type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile">
            </label>
            <?php echo form_error('userfile') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-20 fr">
        <label class="opacity">Hidden</label>
        <input class="fonte-padrao-titulos black" type="submit" value="<?php echo $this->lang->line('botao_form'); ?>">
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require getcwd() . '/vendor/autoload.php';

class TrabalheConosco extends Application_Controller {

    public function index(){
        $this->load->template("trabalhe-conoscoView",$this->data);
    }

    public function enviar(){   
        $this->load->helper("file_upload");

        $config = array(
            'upload_path' => getcwd() . '/upload/',
            'allowed_types' => 'doc|docx|pdf',
            'max_size' => 8196
        );

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nome','Nome','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('telefone','Telefone','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('interesse','Área de Interesse','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("<span class='form-error'>","</span>");

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');

            $dados_form = $this->input->post();
            $html = '<p>Nome: '.$dados_form["nome"].' '.$dados_form["sobrenome"].'</p>
                     <p>Email: '.$dados_form["email"].'</p>
                     <p>Telefone: '.$dados_form["telefone"].'</p>
                     <p>Área de Interesse: '.$dados_form["interesse"].'</p>';

            $destino = 'meuemail@site.com';

            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

            $mail->setFrom('rh@site.com', 'RH'); //Name is optional
            $mail->isHTML(true); 
            $mail->Subject   = 'Trabalhe Conosco';
            $mail->Body      = $html;
            $mail->addAddress($destino);

            if (isset($_FILES) && $_FILES['userfile']['name'] !== '') {
                $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['userfile']['name']);
            }

            if ($mail->send()) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success','E-mail enviado com sucesso!');
                redirect("pt/trabalhe-conosco");
            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Erro no envio. Tente novamente mais tarde!');
                echo $this->email->print_debugger();
            }

        }else{
            $this->load->template("trabalhe-conoscoView",$this->data);
        }
    }
}
```